# Cloudkit Database New Record does not save

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Please keep in mind that this is the first time I have used this website.

I am a complete beginner in coding who, somehow, ended up responsible for creating an app for a high-school level competition. My knowledge is extremely limited and I have found it difficult to find clear tutorials on how to use a CloudKit database.

My task for this specific portion of my application was to make a "Create a Profile" page, where users can input information that will then be stored and displayed in other ViewControllers of the application.

Most of the code related to the database was given by a teacher (taken out from the project of another group), yet its use was not explained. So, I simply tried to copy it and adapt it to the best of my abilities.

However, when running the simulator and creating a test profile, nothing happens once the save button is clicked.

My current code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

let database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase


@IBOutlet weak var profileType: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextfield: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextfield: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var addressTextfield: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextfield: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var phoneTextfield: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()

{

super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated

}


@IBAction func saveProfile(sender: AnyObject) {

let newrecord = CKRecord(recordType: "PotLuck")


 newrecord.setObject(nameTextfield.text as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "CompanyName")

 newrecord.setObject(addressTextfield.text as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "CompanyLocation")

 newrecord.setObject(emailTextfield.text as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "CompanyEmail")

 newrecord.setObject(passwordTextfield.text as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "CompanyPassword")

 newrecord.setObject(phoneTextfield.text as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "CompanyPhone")


 switch profileType.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
       newrecord.setObject("Business" as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "CompanyType")
    case 1:
   newrecord.setObject("Charity" as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "CompanyType")

    default:
        break;
    }

database.saveRecord(newrecord, completionHandler: {newrecord, error in

if error != nil {
   print("An error occured")
} else {

   let newview = URLViewController(nibName: "URLViewControler", bundle: nil)

   self.presentViewController(newview, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
   }
  )
}
```

Would anyone be able to point out whatever is missing or incorrect?

Comment: Please fix your post. Your code is terribly formatted and half the code you posted is commented out. Please only post relevant code and please format it so it is properly indented and readable.